# Some product sales not showing up on Product Ordered Report 1.9.1

Tags: product, reports

When I use the **Reports > Products > Products ordered**, I have some products in there which are reporting sales of 0 over the last 3 months when I know that we have sales for most of these products and in one instance, the sales have been over 50.
This doesn't happen on all products, just a handful, most are simple products.

Any ideas please?